# ASPX Windows Authentication and Not

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis

I want to provide the results of a SQL Server query to a specific set of users without giving those users access to the database itself.

**Query the Database:**

The following ASP.NET Web App code (when published) successfully connects to the database as `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool` and displays the query results.

`<asp:GridView runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" ID="myGridView"/>`

```
string connStr  = "Server=MyHost;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=Yes;";
string queryStr = "SELECT Name, DateCreated FROM MyTable;";

SqlConnection sqlConn     = new SqlConnection(connStr);
SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryStr, sqlConn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
sqlAdapter.Fill(ds);
myGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
myGridView.DataBind();
```

**Attempt at authentication:**
I tried enabling Windows Authentication (`<authentication mode="Windows"/>` in `web.config`. My intention was to get the username with the following code and compare to my list of approved users:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();
```

With Windows Authentication, the web app runs as the client user, and I can verify if that user is in my list. However, the web app fails to connect to the database, as that user does not have database permissions.

**Question:** How do I restrict this webpage so only a specific set of users can view it while still connecting to the database as `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool`?

Comment: Are you using impersonation?

Comment: Yes.  For Windows authentication, my web.config also has `<identity impersonate="true"/>`.

Comment: And why do you have that? If you use impersonation with connection strings that use integrated security, then it will use the user's identity to access the database, which you don't want.

Comment: I want Windows authentication to determine the user accessing the page.  If the user is in my list, then the page will query the database, as `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool`.

Comment: Yes, but you do not need impersonation for that. Impersonation does the opposite of that.

Comment: I need impersonation ON to determine who is logged in, so I can verify the user is in my list.  I need impersonation OFF, so `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool` can connect to the database.  This is my problem.

Comment: No, you don't need impersonation on so you can verify the user is in your list. That's what enabling Windows Authentication gives you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167668/discussion-between-steven-and-mason).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString()`. That's how you get the current user the application pool is running as, not the logged in user. You can force them to be the same by enabling impersonation, but then it will use the impersonated user's account when you use Integrated Security to access the database. Which you've explicitly said you don't want.

- Enable Windows Authentication
- Disable Impersonation
- Use `Request.User.Identity.Name` (when in a Web Forms control or page) or `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.User.Identity.Name` elsewhere (or pass the username from your Web Forms context).
- Use Integrated Security to access the database.